# Data Validation Excel Auto Fill List

Tags: excel, list, autofill

If i create a list of 3 items. e.g.

```
Green1
Blue2
Yellow3
```

I rename as 'colours' in the name box. If i go to data validation - allow - list. Then the source as =colours

When the list is created i select Green1 - enter. Then drag that down more cells. Is there anyway to prevent it going to 'Green2';'Green3' etc.

I just want to drag down cells and then to just show 'Green1' etc.

Comment: As an alternative to dragging, you can highlight your data validation cell, click and select down to the last cell you want this in and press `CTRL+D`. Does that work?

Comment: That does work. Thanks. However, its going to be used a shared workbook. So i couldn't rely on everyone else doing that. Most just drag down